# Instantiate property based on ID without duplicating code

Tags: c#, generics, instantiation

I am trying to find a way to achieve switch case like behavior during instantiation of an object with different properties.

My object looks like this

```
class FooProperty
{
    Nullable<int> IntergerValue {get; set;}
    Nullable<bool> BoolValue {get; set;}
    Nullable<float> FloatValue {get; set;}
    string StringValue {get; set;}
}
```

I need to instantiate instances of my class based on an interger which maps the type to the property - the instantiate function I am designing looks like this:

```
public void Instantiate(int mappingKey, object value)
{
    //Instantiate either interger, bool, float or string based on mappingKey
}
```

The key point here is that I **DO NOT** want to make a switch case like this

```
switch(mappingKey)
{
    case 1:
        new FooProperty
        {
            IntergetValue = (int) value
        };
        break;
    case 2:
        //BoolValue etc.
}
```

Due to extensive code duplication. I am thinking there must be a smarter way to decide which property to instantiate without duplication the object instantiation each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This design seems broken. If the properties within `FooProperty` (btw. a horrible name for a class) are only set depending on a switch making a `FooProperty` for a string having nothing in common with one for type `int` they shouldn´t be reflected by a common class. When using a class all members within that class should belong together in some sense which isn´t the case in your program.

However you can use generics for that:

```
class FooProperty<T>
{
    T Value {  get; set; }
}
```

To create instances call this:

```
var foo = new FooProperty<string>();
foo.Value = "Hell World";
```

Now you can´t assign an int-value to `FooProperty.Value` as it´s of type string.

You can also create a factory-method that creates instances of `FooProperty`:

```
static FooProperty<T> Instantiate<T>(T value)
{
    return new FooProperty<T> { Value = value };
}
```

which you can easily call like this:

```
var newInstance = Instantiate("Hello World")
```

for a string or

```
var newInstance = Instantiate(3);
```

for an int-property.